# iziModal with angularJS ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, modalpopup

I'm using iziModal with AngularJS and I'm having some trouble using ng-click inside the modal. Once the modal popup (created using iziModal) is opened everything seems to work perfectly except ng-click.

Any ideas of what it might be?

this is the function that is not working:

```
$scope.trigger = function() {
  alert("this is an alert");
};
```

I call it here in the following div that represents the modal:

```
<div id="{{client.name}}">
  {{client.surname}}
  <button ng-click="trigger()">click me!!</button>
</div>
```

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqrNECmW0aKBmWE1rM0B?p=preview)

Thank you :)

Comment: You'll have to include the code where you create the modal. Its possible it makes its own scope that has "client" but not your trigger function

Comment: I just tried adding the function within initModal and/or triggerModal. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

in izimodal you have the afterRender attribute, which you can use like this:

```
$("#modal").iziModal({
    afterRender: function() {
        $('#select').on('change', function () {
            /* things */
        });
        $('#button').click(function () {
            /* things */
        });
    }
});
```